# Integrating Unity With Native IOS Code failure

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am integrating unity app into native ios app. i am facing issue related to some classes .I followed this [link](https://jiulongw.github.io/post/embed-unity-in-ios-swift-project/).This link have a demo i follow all steps but did't integrate. I have attached snap that contains issue. Please help me to out here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. For me it was because I wasn't properly signing off on the program to let apple know it was safe.

Follow this tutorial carefully:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing

Pay special attention to setting up the player settings and setting up your account in Xcode.

For me, I still got an error about signing mismatches. In Xcode, I had to click on the "general" tab and manually make sure all the signatures were set to my apple personal developer account, so they all matched up.